# What to do with 'NA' in a database table's datetime column?

Tags: sql, database, ssis

Does anybody know the best ways to handle 'NA' values in a datetime column of a SQL Server database. I'm converting nvarchars to datetime and as 'NA' is not the same NULL I can't just convert it to one. The column is the date a property became vacant and 'NA' means that it is not vacant but there are also NULL values in the column, meaning that it is not know if the property is vacant. What would be the best approach so as to not lose information? (short of sending someone out to check the properties)
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you should replace the value with `NULL` and have another column explaining the reason or source of the value.

Comment: To expand on Gordon's recommendation, I would add a column called IsDateTimeColumnSourceNull and make it a bit value.

Comment: Thanks Gordon and J, seems obvious when you think about it. The best solutions often are

Comment: or you can agree with business to put them as '01/01/1900' or '09/09/9999' . Business needs to decide on the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to set the value to the maximum future value allowed by the datatype.  Any date in the future should indicate that the property is not *currently* vacant, right?

Comment: I considered mentioning that solution (i.e., 12-31-9999), but that can be tricky from a future perspective in the event that a query that uses a date lookup with the BETWEEN clause (with the end date being 12-31-9999) then these NA columns could be returned. Further, from a functional standpoint, any real date becomes a legitimate date where NA is not a date. Respectfully, I would not recommend this solution - I think a second indicator column would be a cleaner and safer solution.

Comment: @JWeezy whether this is a viable solution or not definitely depends on how the data will be consumed.  The front end would have to be programmed around this usage for it to work.